# Postgresql: Adding in a count that counts the number of instances present to that point

Tags: postgresql, counter

I am trying to add a column into my data that counts how many of events happened up to that point. (so not the total, just how many happened previously).  See an example below:

```
Store#  Event    Date         (New column: count)
12       Sale     1/1/2017     1
12       Sale     2/1/2017     2
14       Sale     1/1/2017     1
12       Sale     3/1/2017     3
14       Sale     3/1/2017     2
12       Sale     4/1/2017     4
```

I know that I will have to add in a loop, but not sure how. Any and all help would be most appreciated!

Comment: What if a row that gets added later makes the new column wrong? And even if that cannot happen: it would maybe be better *not* to store that information in the table, but compute it when you need it.

Comment: That would make it easier, but I need it to then creating a pivoting table.  I need the final result to show how many sales there were and on what dates they happened, one row per store.  So the final result headers would be (with the respective values below it):                                `Store#         sale_cnt      date 1     date2    date3    date4`